# What is Pairwise Distinct?

Tags: math

I am trying to solve a question in which i have given an array of unsorted element and it ask to choose 
three pairwise distinct index from array at a time to sort the array.
So my question is what is  **Pairwise Distinct**  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collection of k items are pairwise distinct if no two of them are equal to one another. For example, the values 1, 2, and 3 are pairwise distinct, but the values 1, 1, and 3 are not.

Comment: let suppose i have an array of element 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6 is this a pairwise distinct ?

Comment: No, since the values 2 and 1 appear twice.

Comment: if i make 2 pair from the above array like [ 1, 2, 3, 4] and [2, 1, 6], then the both the 2 sub-array are pairwise distinct , am i right ?

Comment: Without more context I can't be 100% sure, since I wouldn't think of those as "pairs," but I'm fairly sure that's the case. Perhaps you should ask whoever gave you this problem?

Comment: How's that different than merely saying "distinct"? Why say "pairwise distinct" instead of just "distinct"?

Comment: That’s a fair question - I’m not actually sure!